# Wait & Signal order

Tags: c, pthreads, semaphore

If the following pieces of code execute in the order in which I have put them, can I be sure that thread 1 is awoken first by thread 3, later followed by thread 2?

```
main:
sem_init(&x,0,0);

thread 1:
sem_wait(&x);

thread 2:
sem_wait(&x);

thread 3:
sem_post(&x);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to make such an assumption. It depends on when thread 1 and thread 2 are invoquing sem_wait(), i.e., on what they do before and how the scheduler gives them CPU for running. If you want that thread 1 be awoken before thread 2, you need another semaphore:

```
main:
sem_init(&x,0,0);
sem_init(&y,0,0);

thread 1:
sem_wait(&x);
sem_post(&y);

thread 2:
sem_wait(&y);

thread 3:
sem_post(&x);
```

Comment: Even with this code, one should realize that even though thread 1 becomes runnable before thread 2 there's still not necessarily a guarantee that it'll be scheduled to run before thread 2.  If there's work that thread 1 needs to do before thread 2 runs, then the `sem_post(&y)` (or equivalent) needs to be done by thread 1.